# Coding smoother Shooting Recoil

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So, I started following a tutorial and then added some other things that I needed and everything works fine, even the recoil, but the problem is that it is really choppy, it moves once a frame and it isn't smooth at all (which is what I want) I don't know a lot about programming so I hope you can help me :)

My code:

```
    using System.Collections;
    using UnityEngine;
    using UnityEngine.UI;
    using UnityEngine.Audio;

    public class GunController : MonoBehaviour
    {
    [Header("Gun Setting")]
    public float fireRate = 0.1f;
    public int clipSize = 30;
    public int reservedAmmoCapacity = 270;

    //Variables that change throughout the code
    bool canShoot;
    int _currentAmmoInClip;
    int _ammoInReserve;

    //Muzzle Flash
    public ParticleSystem muzzleFlash;

    //Aiming
    public Vector3 normalLocalPosition;
    public Vector3 aimingLocalPosition;

    public float aimSmoothing = 10;

    [Header("Mouse Settings")]
    public float mouseSensitivity = 1;
    Vector2 _currentRotation;
    public float weaponSwayAmount = 10;

    //Weapon Recoil
    public bool randomizeRecoil;
    public Vector2 randomRecoilConstraints;

    //You only need to assign if randomize recoil is off
    public Vector2[] recoilPattern;

    //Audio
    AudioSource shootingSound;

    //Reloading
    public float reloadTime = 1.5f;



    private void Start()
    {
        _currentAmmoInClip = clipSize;
        _ammoInReserve = reservedAmmoCapacity;
        canShoot = true;
        shootingSound = GetComponent<AudioSource>();
    }


    private void Update()
    {
        DetermineAim();
        DetermineRotation();

        if (Input.GetMouseButton(0) && canShoot && _currentAmmoInClip > 0)
        {
            shootingSound.Play();
            StartCoroutine(FinishShooting());
            muzzleFlash.Play();
            canShoot = false;
            _currentAmmoInClip--;
            StartCoroutine(ShootGun());
        }


        else if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.R) && _currentAmmoInClip < clipSize && _ammoInReserve > 0)
        {
            StartCoroutine(Reload());
        }
    }

    void DetermineRotation()
    {
        Vector2 mouseAxis = new Vector2(Input.GetAxisRaw("Mouse X"), Input.GetAxisRaw("Mouse Y"));

        mouseAxis *= mouseSensitivity;
        _currentRotation += mouseAxis;

        _currentRotation.y = Mathf.Clamp(_currentRotation.y, -90, 90);

        transform.localPosition += (Vector3)mouseAxis * weaponSwayAmount / 1000;

        transform.root.localRotation = Quaternion.AngleAxis(_currentRotation.x, Vector3.up);
        transform.parent.localRotation = Quaternion.AngleAxis(-_currentRotation.y, Vector3.right);
    }

    void DetermineAim()
    {
        Vector3 target = normalLocalPosition;
        if (Input.GetMouseButton(1)) target = aimingLocalPosition;

        Vector3 desiredPosition = Vector3.Lerp(transform.localPosition, target, Time.deltaTime * aimSmoothing);

        transform.localPosition = desiredPosition;
    }
    void DetermineRecoil()
    {
        transform.localPosition -= Vector3.forward * 0.1f;

        if (randomizeRecoil)
        {
            float xRecoil = Random.Range(-randomRecoilConstraints.x, randomRecoilConstraints.x);
            float yRecoil = Random.Range(-randomRecoilConstraints.y, randomRecoilConstraints.y);

            Vector2 recoil = new Vector2(xRecoil, yRecoil);

            _currentRotation += recoil;
        }
        else
        {
            int currentStep = clipSize + 1 - _currentAmmoInClip;
            currentStep = Mathf.Clamp(currentStep, 0, recoilPattern.Length - 1);

            _currentRotation += recoilPattern[currentStep];
        }
    }

    IEnumerator ShootGun()
    {
        _currentAmmoInClip -= 1;


        DetermineRecoil();

        RayCastEnemy();
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(fireRate);
        canShoot = true;
    }

    void RayCastEnemy()
    {
        RaycastHit hit;
        if (Physics.Raycast(transform.parent.position, transform.parent.forward, out hit, 1 << LayerMask.NameToLayer("Enemy")))
        {
            try
            {
                Debug.Log("Hit an enemy");
                Rigidbody rb = hit.transform.GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
                rb.constraints = RigidbodyConstraints.None;
                rb.AddForce(transform.parent.transform.forward * 50);
            }
            catch { }
        }
    }

    IEnumerator FinishShooting()
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.3f);

        shootingSound.Stop();
    }

    IEnumerator Reload()
    {
        canShoot = false;
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(reloadTime);
        int amountNeeded = clipSize - _currentAmmoInClip;
        if (amountNeeded > _ammoInReserve)
        {
            _currentAmmoInClip += _ammoInReserve;
            _ammoInReserve -= amountNeeded;
            canShoot = true;
        }
        else
        {
            canShoot = false;
            _currentAmmoInClip = clipSize;
            _ammoInReserve -= amountNeeded;
            canShoot = true;
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

I don't see the function `DetermineRecoil()` called anywhere in the code, but  maybe this solution will work:

```
let _currentRotation = Vector2.Lerp(_currentRotation, _currentRotation + recoilPattern[currentStep], 10*Time.deltaTime);
```

It will change the value of `_currentRotation` smoothly.

Comment: Hi, your solution did not work, it made the recoil not exist at all and also DetermineRecoil is called in IEnumerator ShootGun.